# Add ZeroWidthChar in Quarkus logs

Tags: quarkus, grafana-loki, promtail

I want to configure a multi-line processor using PLG stack (Promtail, Loki & Grafana) with Quarkus services. I am following this [link](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/stages/multiline/) to do so, but I am unable to inject the zero-width-character in my quarkus-app/application.properties file: it either print it as is or replace it with a ?. Here is what I tried so far :

```
quarkus.log.console.format=U+200B%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p traceId=%X{traceId}, parentId=%X{parentId}, spanId=%X{spanId}, sampled=%X{sampled} [%c{2.}] (%t) %s%e%n

quarkus.log.console.format=&ZeroWidthSpace;%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p traceId=%X{traceId}, parentId=%X{parentId}, spanId=%X{spanId}, sampled=%X{sampled} [%c{2.}] (%t) %s%e%n
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why that isn't working for you - you could try the alternate representations such  as `&#8203;` or `&#x200B;` or perhaps the java Unicode `\u200B` e.g.

```
quarkus.log.console.format=\u200B%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p traceId=%X{traceId}, parentId=%X{parentId}, spanId=%X{spanId}, sampled=%X{sampled} [%c{2.}] (%t) %s%e%n
```

If none of those work and you can't get any Zero-width space to render as you like then as the document says...

> "Any special character that is unlikely to be part of your regular
> logs should do just fine"

So perhaps you could just tilde `~`, or asterisk `*`, or some other non alpha-numeric symbol?

e.g.

tilde

```
quarkus.log.console.format=~{HH:mm:ss} %-5p traceId=%X{traceId}, parentId=%X{parentId}, spanId=%X{spanId}, sampled=%X{sampled} [%c{2.}] (%t) %s%e%n
```

Edit: you could also just paste a `Zero-width space` in - but obviously it will look like there is nothing there :)

```
quarkus.log.console.format=​{HH:mm:ss} %-5p traceId=%X{traceId}, parentId=%X{parentId}, spanId=%X{spanId}, sampled=%X{sampled} [%c{2.}] (%t) %s%e%n
```

[image: example of pasted zero-width space]

Comment: Did you try it before ? I tried all the above with no luck!
Also I can't bet to replace random special character like what you suggested: if there is another match in the same line it will be splitted into separate line in Loki/Grafana.

Comment: @iabughosh - hmm I see what you mean, but `Zero-width space` is also just a "random special character" - and you know 100% that it won't be in the log right? So then surly there should be others too...I mean - take your pick! - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters - `ɏ`, `☔`, `⛇` etc

Comment: If I want to think  of a way it maybe 2 or 3 special characters combination but definitely not one special char.

Comment: @iabughosh - but `Zero-width space` is just one special char - so you are basically saying that won't work either? There is nothing "magic" about that particular char except that it is a `non-printing character`. Thinking about it - you could also try and paste it in (although it will look like it isn't there) see my edit.

Comment: What I am saying is the zero-width space characters is not working in any form, so I may do something like '~#' as a multiline indicator